# ARDUINO flashing lights

Tags: programming, led, loop

I'm making a circuit with my Arduino so that when it receives a '1' or
'2' or 'a' it turns on or off the LEDS. But I wanted the lights to
flash and do not know how to do loops in loops or if that's what I
need to do at all. Any help would be very much appreciated and the
code will be below.

```
//-----------------ELECTRONICS-----------------//

int left = 11;
int stoP = 12;
int right = 8;

//variables
int Received = 0;
int left_state =0;
int stoP_state = 0;
int right_state = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(left,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stoP,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right,OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    Received = Serial.read();
  }

////////////////LEFT//////////////////

if (left_state == 0 && Received == '1')

{
  digitalWrite(left,HIGH);  
  Received = 0;
  left_state = 1;
}

if (left_state == 1 && Received == '1')

{
  digitalWrite(left,LOW);
  Received = 0;
  left_state = 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////


///////////////stop////////////////

if (stoP_state == 0 && Received == 'a')

{
  digitalWrite(stoP,HIGH);  
  Received = 0;
  stoP_state = 1;
}

if (stoP_state == 1 && Received == 'a')

{
  digitalWrite(stoP,LOW);
  Received = 0;
  stoP_state = 0;
}

 ////////////////////////////////

 ///////////right///////////////

if (right_state == 0 && Received == '2')

{
  digitalWrite(right,HIGH);  
  Received = 0;
  right_state = 1;
}

if (right_state == 1 && Received == '2')

{
  digitalWrite(right,LOW);
  Received = 0;
  right_state = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You could turn off the LEDs after a short time using `millis()`. You can look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

As chrisl already mentions, you have to use the `millis` function.

Besides setting a pin HIGH, you keep a variable for each state for the start time and set it when the corresponding state is set to 1:

```
unsigned long left_start_time = millis();
```

Than within the loop you check for each state when it is 1 (on or actually flashing) and switch the pin on or off, example:

```
if (left_state == 1)
{
    digitalWrite((millis() - left_startTime % 400) < 400 / 2) ? HIGH : LOW);
}
```

What this does is for the first half of the 400 ms period (time % 400 < 200) to be HIGH, and the last half (time % 400 >= 200) to be LOW.

Improvements:

- Do not use 400 but a constant value.
- Do not use separate variables for left/right/stop, but put them in a structure, keeping the state, time, pin, and activation key ('1', '2', 'a') together.
- If you do the above, you can make your program more simpler (and avoid code duplication) by parameterize your code.